# Python Functions for Calculating and Applying Discount

Tags: python-3.x

Create a Python function called `calculate_discount` that takes two parameters: `original_price` and `discount_percentage`. The function should calculate and return the discounted price. Test the function with different input values to ensure it works correctly. Additionally, design another function `apply_discount` that takes a list of prices and a discount percentage. It should apply the discount to each price in the list and return a new list of discounted prices. Finally, demonstrate the usage of both functions with sample input and output

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  It looks like you are stuck with a homework question.  Please post what you have tried so far and explain which bit you are stuck with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.